# What does hierarchy support do in cgroup?

Tags: linux, kernel, cgroups

`cgroup` has 2 options for memory control:

- `memory.use_hierarchy = 1` : use hierarchy
- `memory.use_hierarchy = 0` : use flat hierarchy, according to [this answer](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1209.0/00867.html)

What is the difference between the two? I think, hierarchy is hierarchy, what does "flat" mean here?

Edit: I read the cgroup documentation [here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt#580) explained the hierarchical support:

> In the diagram above, with hierarchical accounting enabled, all memory
>   usage of e, is accounted to its ancestors up until the root (i.e,
>   c and root), that has memory.use_hierarchy enabled. If one of the
>   ancestors goes over its limit, the reclaim algorithm reclaims from
>   the tasks in the ancestor and the children of the ancestor.

- What does it mean by `accounted to its ancestors up until the root`?
- How can ancestors can go over its limit, since its children capacities are allocated that sum to the capacity of the ancestor?
- Why are tasks reclaimed in both ancestor and children? I thought that tasks are only allocated in the children and those tasks automatically belong to ancestor. i.e. "WWW Browsing" has 20% capacity; its children are "Professors" and "Students" that have 15% and 5% respectively. The maximum can never exceed 20%. Why is there a case in the document stated that:

> If one of the ancestors goes over its limit, the reclaim algorithm
>   reclaims from the tasks in the ancestor and the children of the
>   ancestor.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hierarchical here means that there are memory cgroups nested within cgroups. eg. You can create a parent cgroup P and it can have a child cgroup C. There can be processes in P (say p1 and p2) and in C (c1, c2). With use_hierarchy=1, memory stats at P would show the total of C's usage and usage by all processes in P. It will also account for any tmpfs in P.

If cgroup P goes over limit,  it can reclaim memory from p1, p2, and child cgroup C. If C goes over limit, it will reclaim from c1 and c2.

I think the point that is unclear in documentation is that there can be tasks that are directly under P and not under one of its children cgroups.